# Python - Creating a table using two list and expoting in csv format

Tags: python, dataframe

I have two list in python and i want to convert that in a table and export it as csv file.

```
    print price
    print name

Output:
    [u'\xa34', u'\xa38', u'\xa312', u'\xa30']
    [u'apple', u'orange', u'mango', u'pineapple']
```

The final output i want is:

```
Name         Price
Apple        34
Orange       38
Mango        312
Pineapple    30
```

I tried using pandas but i am unable to do so. Could someone suggest me some link so that i can study about creating a table and exporting it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step 1: Initialise the dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name' : name, 'Price' : price})
```

Step 2: Call `df.to_csv` to export your data to csv format

```
df.to_csv('items.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Comment: Thanx a lot!!:) There is a row number added by default. How do i remove that?

Comment: @sky_bird Edited... You need `index=False`

Comment: @coldspeed

I am getting this error when i am trying to export:

pandas\lib.pyx in pandas.lib.write_csv_rows (pandas\lib.c:19850)()

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: @sky_bird Ah... you need `encoding='utf-8'` as well in `to_csv`.

Comment: Got it, thanx.!

Comment: Yeah, i did it..:)